# Take 1000 using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, enumerable

Ok, my linq skills aren't great so im trying to do the following.

Say I have 6000 records (email address)
I want to add the first 1000 add to bcc, send, 
take the next 1000 add to bcc, send,
take the 1000 add to bcc, send, etc....

Ive started wrinting,

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Mail\ ", "*.csv");

Parallel.ForEach(files, currentFile =>
{
    string filename = currentFile;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
    var emailList = new List<String>();
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        emailList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
    \\Here is where I need to do the linq?
    IEnumerable<string> list = emailList

    var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    foreach (var s in list)
    {
        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(s);
        message.Bcc.Add(mailAddress);
    }

    message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    message.Body = txtMessage.Text;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

    smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: so what is the problem ??

Comment: you don't need Linq for this at all - move your email sending code into a separate method and call that after you have enough addresses in your initial while loop

Comment: @BrokenGlass You never *need* LINQ.  It may or may not be an acceptable tool to use to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be looking for a `Batch` method.  Here is one implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(item);

        if (buffer.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

You can now write:

```
foreach(var batch in emailList.Batch(1000))
{
    var message = CreateMessage();
    foreach(var email in batch)
    {
        message.Bcc.Add(email);
    }
    message.Send();
}
```

On a side note, rather than using a `StreamReader` to read the file's lines, you can use `File.ReadLines` to get an `IEnumerable<string>` representing the lines in the file.  It even has the side benefit of streaming the data rather than pulling *all* of the lines into memory first.

Comment: This way, you would be iterating over all e-mail addresses twice. BrokenGlass' implementation only iterates once. Although technically this answers how to achieve this in Linq.

Comment: @RGraham See the edit at the end; that's a result of the OP using an undesirable mechanism to read the file into memory, which is easily resolved.

Comment: Doesn't `ReadLines` use StreamReader internally? I don't think StreamReader puts everything into memory, does it? And can you provide a source because I've been using it in a lot of cases I really shouldn't have!!

Comment: @RGraham `ReadLines` streams the data yes; it fetches the next line when the enumerator asks for it, rather than all up front.  The OP's code, despite using a `StreamReader`, doesn't stream the data; instead it uses the stream reader to just pull all of it into a list, thus preventing streaming the data.

Answer (score 1):

Move your email sending code into a separate method and call that after you have enough addresses in your initial while loop:

```
var emailList = new List<String>();
while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
{
    emailList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    if(emailList.Count == 1000)
    {
        SendEmails(emailList);
        emailList = new List<String>();
    }
}
//send the rest, if any
if(emailList.Any()) SendEmails(emailList);
```

This is much cleaner imo anyway since your email sending method is logically separated from the way you acquire the email addresses.

Comment: `reader.Peek()` is a real performance killer, `string line; while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { emailList.Add(line);` is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Better still is to just `foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filename))`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it with linq I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/2145211) will do exactly what you are looking for, modified below where you send in group = 1000

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int group)
{
    return  source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / group)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Should This be a comment and not an answer.  Please let me know and I will delete and change if that is the case

Comment: Please explain the -1, thank you.  I can update my answer based on comments not on -1.